# Connect to a self hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

So we have a 3rd party software that has it's own API we use to retrieve calculated data inside application only, when ever we try to run a WCF service through the API it runs, and the state is showing as OPEN but we try to add this Service as a Service Reference we can't connect to it for some reason .

The service port is not showing in opened ports list, could the be due to WCF is started on a different thread(3rd party application thread).

I am following this tutorial :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/11/01/wcf-service-hosting-how-to-host-a-wcf-service-from-inside-a-windows-presentation-foundation-application/

which works fine when we create our own software to host the WCF.

The idea behind using WCF in a 3rd party software is we are trying to access calculated data from this software and get it in another client application.

Please your help is needed.

Comment: Am not really getting what you mean... so the 3rd party software exposes and API... and u read the API through the WCF ???

Comment: No, the 3rd party exposes API only inside the plugin you create for the software(the plugin can have UI through usercontrol) what we want to do is run the WCF service once the plugin is loaded(API call back is started) so we can access data outside the software

Comment: Can you see the WSDL of the WCF?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but were i can find WSDL?

Comment: just call the WCF URL and add `/?wsdl` at the end

Comment: Thanks for the help it turned out the WCF is closing automatically because i am declairing ServiceHost in side a using (){} statement , once i removed the using now the WCF is working fine .

Answer (score 0):

WCF service was no being detected because i have it inside using statement

```
  using(ServiceHost myServ = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAdress))
{

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                myServ.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                myServ.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Services is :" + myServ.State + "\n" + baseAdress);
    }
```

once the using(){} is removed the WCF is working as a charm